# When sending multi select value jquery/ajax data is incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I have multi select drop down menu. When user selects values jquery/ajax request should be sent to the server. Here is example of my code:

```js
$("#send").on("click", function() {
  var elem$ = $("#cars"),
    elemVal = elem$.val();
  console.log(elemVal);
  if (elemVal) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'requestTest.html?fn=saveCar',
      data: {'cars': elemVal},
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(obj) {
      console.log(obj);
    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("An error has occured.");
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cars" id="cars" multiple>
  <option value="">--Select Car--</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<button type="button" name="send" id="send">Send</button>
```

The code ajax call returned an error. It was telling me that cars element is required in my function but it's not passed in. I checked my developer tools and here is what I found under Params:

```
{"cars[]":["volvo","saab"]}
```

It looks that data is not structured properly. I'm wondering what is causing `cars` to get an array in front? What is the best way to fix this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With this code is going to work better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#send").on("click", function() {
      var elem$ = $("#cars").val();
        //elemVal = elem$.val();
      console.log(elem$);
      if (elem$) {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'requestTest.html?fn=saveCar',
          data: {'cars': elem$},
          dataType: 'json'
        }).done(function(obj) {
          console.log(obj);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("An error has occured.");
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
```

This give you an array, this array you can manage it from php:
[Image of my console with this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAJpc.png)